# Automatically close if SAP status message error captured

Tags: vba, sap-gui

How do I stop a SAP GUI script if there any status messages are captured.

I created a SAP GUI script recording and Excel macro for automation.
It works if there's any data collected.
If there's no data collected and will have status bar then the script will error.

I tried to create some code if the status error show up, the script will automatically close. Seems I only can make it work if the error is for "No items selected (see long text)".

Other status errors show up, so I'm thinking to make the status bar capture the whole error if possible.

```
If session.findById("wnd[0]/sbar").Text = "No items selected (see long text)" Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Hi, I've modified and put the code which I use for now, but it only works if that status message appear, sometimes can be different message. So i'm trying to make the code captured all type of status message if possible

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the messagetype of the status bar. If it is `E` then you've got an error.

Instead checking for the text like in your code you check for the messagetype

```
If session.findById("wnd[0]/sbar").MessageType= "E" Then
  ' Whatever code is needed here
Exit Sub

End If
```